# Javascript Variable Declaration with ||

Tags: javascript

I'm investigating Three.js at the moment and have come across this variable declaration at the top of the main source file:

```
var THREE = THREE || { REVISION: '52' };
```

I'm just wondering what the OR (||) is doing in there - what is the function of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above means:

If the value of `THREE` evaluates to `true`, assign the value of `THREE` to the `THREE` variable, otherwise initialize it to the object `{ REVISION: '52' }`.

Comment: It tests if `THREE` evaluates as true, not if it is defined.

Comment: @Quentin - Answer updated - better?

Answer (score 1):

In code, it's like saying:

```
var THREE;
if (THREE) {
    THREE = { REVISION: '52' };
}
else {
    THREE = THREE;
}
```

Or:

```
var THREE = (THREE) ? { REVISION: '52' } : THREE;
```

Comment: What if `THREE` was `0`?

Comment: @Quentin Good point! Hope I got it right now(?) =)

Answer (score 0):

lazy instantiation. If the variable is declared already, then assign a value to it.